# Sequelize - return new field based on value of another field

Tags: sequelize.js

I have my a Sequelize function that returns all my users in the DB based on a single condition and it works great.  Now I want to add a field to the returned fields that is created and depends on a value from a field.  So if `reset_link` is `NULL`, I would return `status` as one value, otherwise return `status` as a different value.

I realize I could just return the `reset_link` but I don't want to return that value if I don't have to.

Here is my current findAll function.

```js
const users = await db.User.findAll({
                raw: true,
                attributes: [
                    ['id', 'userID'],
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                    'email',
                    'phone',
                    'Permission.type'
                    // 'Permission.id'
                ],
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.Permission,
                        where: { id: { [Op.gt]: 3 } },
                        attributes: []
                    }
                ],
                where: { customer_id: args.customer_id },
                order: [[{ model: db.Permission }, 'id', 'ASC']]
            });
```

Comment: I assume you want `status` to be inside users' records. Then you have two options is to map over all users and implement this logic in your conde OR add the virtual User's status field and put that logic there. The second option will not work if the `reset_link` param is not part of model attributes.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to do it with the virtual fields.